# Зерновых культур намолочено (или намолочена) 261 тыс. тонн. - как правильно писать

Tags: орфография

Зерновых культур намолочено (или намолочена) 261 тыс. тонн. - как правильно писать?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Зерновых культур **намолочено**  261 тыс. тонн.*

**[ПРАВИЛО](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)**

**§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)**

В общем сказуемое может иметь как форму единственного, так и форму множественного числа.

3. Форма **единственного числа** сказуемого употребляется при обозначении **меры веса,** пространства, времени и т.д., так как в этом случае имеется в виду **единое целое,** например: На покраску крыши ушло двадцать килограммов олифы; До конца пути оставалось пятнадцать километров; На выполнение всей работы понадобится шесть месяцев.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

*Зерновых культур **намолочено**  1 тыс. тонн.*

Думаю, что ответ не изменится. Здесь важно отметить то, что "зерновых культур" стоит на **первом** месте, так что нет прямого контакта с числом. Поэтому возможная **несогласованность** не отмечается на слух.

Для сравнения: *До конца пути **оставался километр**.* Здесь согласование делается по форме. А в нашем случае согласование не по форме (**тысяча намолочена**), а по семантике.

Comment: а если намолочено 1 тыс. тонн

Comment: Дополнение в ответе